# How to unzip a file and access contents in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zip

I have an issue that I've been struggling with for a few days.

I'm needing to display a 3D model in the browser, which I know how to do. The issue is that my user is going to upload a .zip file of their 3D model, and I need to parse it so that I can tell my Three.js component to read the files.

Here is the contents of the zip file:

```
object_file.obj
material_file.mtl
materials/
    texture1.jpg
    texture2.jpg
```

The `.mtl` file references the `materials/` folder in it's contents, which basically tells the model where to look for the textures.

So essentially, I need to somehow unzip these files and have access to them like I would if they were stored locally.

The user is currently uploading the file using the `<input type="file">....` method. I don't need it to be uploaded to any server or anything yet. Basically, when I get the file using `const file = event.target.files[0]`, I need to access the content as explained above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper this library?

Comment: @SunnySultan - This is for server side isn't it?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, Its for server-side only.

Comment: Can you try this https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

Comment: also, here is a demo https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo2.html